# ZMQ event publisher in Jenkins doesn't send a notification

Tags: jenkins, zeromq, pyzmq

I have been trying to figure out what is wrong with my Jenkins ZMQ-event-publisher configuration for more than 23 hours and have given up. Hopefully, you may have an idea what I am doing wrong.

- I've installed Jenkins with [ZMQ-event-publisher](http://git.openstack.org/cgit/openstack-infra/zmq-event-publisher) plugin and under `Manage Jenkins`->`Configure System` checked `Enable on all Jobs` (**Note** `TCP port to publish on` is set to `8888`).
- Created a new job, checked `Check if ZMQ events should be published for this project` and clicked on `Save`.
- I have written a Python script using [pyZMQ](http://zeromq.org/bindings:python)

  ```
  #!/usr/bin/env python
  import zmq
  port = "8888"
  context = zmq.Context()
  socket = context.socket(zmq.SUB)

  socket.connect("tcp://localhost:%s" % port)
  socket.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, '')
  print "Jenkins... waiting..."
  string = socket.recv()
  print "recv =>", string
  ```
- Executing the above script on the Jenkins machine + running the Jenkins job.

Unfortunately, the script doesn't receive any ZMQ message from Jenkins.
Trying to capture the ZMQ message using either `tcpdump -i eth0 'port 8888'` or `tcpdump -i lo 'port 8888'` didn't help too.

In addition to that, looking at the `/var/log/jenkins/jenkins.log`, I get:

```
Sep 25, 2014 8:54:47 PM org.jenkinsci.plugins.ZMQEventPublisher.ZMQRunnable bindSocket
INFO: Binding ZMQ PUB to port 8888
Sep 25, 2014 8:54:48 PM hudson.model.Run execute
INFO: MyJob #18 main build action completed: SUCCESS
```

Moreover, `netstat -ntlp` verifies that

```
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address               Foreign Address             State       PID/Program name   
tcp        0      0 :::8888                     :::*                        LISTEN      31/java             
tcp        0      0 :::57467                    :::*                        LISTEN      31/java             
tcp        0      0 :::8009                     :::*                        LISTEN      31/java             
tcp        0      0 :::59373                    :::*                        LISTEN      31/java             
tcp        0      0 :::8080                     :::*                        LISTEN      31/java
```

So, what am I doing wrong? 
There is no good explanation on how to configure correctly the Jenkins ZMQ plugin and looking at the plugin code doesn't reveal much.

Your help will be more than appreciated.

Thanks.

**EDIT** : Dave's suggestion was great, but it hasn't fixed the problem, yet.

**EDIT 2**: It looks like it fails because Jenkins has been running from a Docker container and I've forgotten to expose all its ports. Nevertheless, It looks like Dave's suggestions does fix the problem. Yay!!!

Comment: Note that `tcpdump -i eth0` isn't going to show you anything since you're communicating with localhost. You'd have to do `tcpdump -i lo`

Comment: Hi nos, thanks. Unfortunately, running `tcpdump -i lo 'port 8888'` didn't capture anything. :\. I did `tcpdump -i lo` but only reset(R) and sync(S) communication are captured.

Comment: Ok, you are running your python script on the same host as your jenkins server, right ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [ZMQ Guide](http://zguide.zeromq.org/page:all#Getting-the-Message-Out):

> Note that when you use a SUB socket you must set a subscription using zmq_setsockopt() and SUBSCRIBE

I suspect that your subscriber script is not seeing events because you need to set the subscribe filter. As described on the [zmq_setsockopt page](http://api.zeromq.org/3-2:zmq-setsockopt#toc6), setting the filter to the empty string subscribes to all messages.

Try adding:

```
socket.setsockopt(zmq.SUBSCRIBE, '')
```

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks for your reply. However, I still don't get any ZMQ message. Thanks for noticing, though!

Comment: Sorry it's not working for you. Your script received an event on my clean Jenkins install (1.581) with ZMQ-event-publisher plugin 0.0.3. I made sure to start the subscriber script before running the Jenkins job (because the publisher discards events if nothing is subscribed).

Comment: Well, after your comment, I ran Jenkins on a VM (instead of on a Docker container) and it did work! So -- I guess this problem was resolved. ta